# Cron doesn't seems to work with .php extension file

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, cron

I have added the following code to /etc/crontab:

```
0 0 * * * curl  http://url.com/cron.php
30 9 * * * curl http://url.com/cron_ads.php
30 15 * * * curl http://url.com/cron_clean.php
```

But it doesn't seem to work at all. When I run the cron job manually it works but not automatically. I have php-cli installed and php-curl, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

CRON does not populate the PATH environment variable - therefore you MUST use absolute pathnames. So instead of just `curl` you should probably write `/usr/bin/curl` or whatever is the absolute path.

Comment: Well, your usage of `curl` implies that the CRON job's purpose is to download the file from the given URL. Nothing more. If you in addition want to execute the downloaded PHP script - then you obviously have to run the PHP interpreter (either implicitly or by running the script itself - if the script begins with `#!/usr/bin/php`)